# In React when in onChange function how to update another custom component's state and pass a value in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, onchange

In a React app currently there is a drop down list that has an onChange event that calls a function. In that function (when the users selects a different choice in the ddl) what I would like to achive is to update another custom component & pass a value into that component.

So in the front end there is a simple drop down:

```
    <Dropdown
        value={selectedOption}
        options={dropDownOptions}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
```

Then there is an onChange function that gets fired when the drop down gets selected:

```
 const onChange = React.useCallback(
    e => {
      const optionId = e.target.value;
      const optionData = keyedOptions[optionId];

      // refresh DownloadSelector custom component
      // something like this which doesn't work {optionData.id && <DownloadSelector eventId={optionData.id} />} }
```

Also I am able to import the custom component at the top of the file normally such as:

```
import { DownloadSelector } from '../../../SearchAndSort/DownloadSelector';
```

The custom component when defining it has a value passed in like so:

```
export const DownloadSelector = ({eventId}) => {
```

If the whole page refreshes the custom `DownloadSelector` component will get uploaded. I would like that to happen in the onChange.

How in the onChange function can we update/reload/setState/refresh the `DownloadSelector` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my question is in the custom component that I wanted to rerender when the drop down ( a different component) is changed is to define the variables that are changing in the custom component `DownloadSelector` in state (not a local let) such as:

```
  const [isMyVar] = useState(false);
```

Then when `isMyVar` is updated the state changed & the component rerenders. The answer was not (what I originally thought) was to have the code in the onChange event of the 2nd component. I appreciate @Hostek for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [eventId, setEventId] = React.useState()

const onChange = React.useCallback(() {
  // ....

  // replace newState with a updated value
  setEventId( newState )
}, [])

return <DownloadSelector eventId={eventId} />
```

Comment: thank you @Hostek; I am not able to return the `DownloadSelector` since the file already is returning the dropDownList component. Are we able to update the `DownloadSelector` component inside the onChange function?

Comment: I'll add new answer.

Answer (score 1):

In DownloadSelector do something like this:

```
function useForceUpdate(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0); // integer state
    return () => setValue(value => value + 1); // update state to force render
}

const DownloadSelector = ({eventId}) => {
  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

  // ....

  return <Dropdown 
          value={selectedOption}
          options={dropDownOptions}
          onChange={onChange}
          forceUpdate={forceUpdate}
        />
}
```

And then in onChange in Dropdown Component:

```
const onChange = React.useCallback(() {
  // ....

  forceUpdate()
}, [])
```